# Series: $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left( \prod_{i = 1}^n (2i - 1) \middle/ \prod_{i = 1}^n 2i \right)^k $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

In Section 10.16 of Apostol's *Calculus* (Problem 18), the reader is asked to prove that the series

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left( \prod_{i = 1}^n (2i - 1) \middle/ \prod_{i = 1}^n 2i \right)^k $$

converges if $k > 2$ and diverges if $k \leq 2$ using Gauss's test. In the text, Gauss's test is given as follows. If there is an $N \geq 1$, an $s > 1$, and an $M > 0$ such that $a_{n + 1}/a_n = 1 - A/n + f(n)/n^s$ for all $n \geq N$, where $|f(n)| \leq M$ for all $n > 0$, then $\sum a_n$ converges if $A > 1$ and diverges if $A \leq 1$. Letting $a_n$ be the terms of the indicated sequence, we use the binomial series to obtain

$$\begin{align}
   \frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n} ~ = ~ & \left( \frac{2n + 1}{2n + 2} \right)^k \\
                 ~ = ~ & \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2n + 2} \right)^k && \\
                 ~ = ~ & \sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} {k \choose i} \left(\frac{-1}{2n + 2} \right)^i \\
                 ~ = ~ & 1 - \frac{k}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n + 1}\right) + \sum_{i = 2}^{\infty}{k \choose i}\left(\frac{-1}{2n + 2} \right)^i \\
                 ~ = ~ & 1 - \frac{k}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) + \left( \sum_{i = 2}^{\infty}{k \choose i}\left(\frac{-1}{2n + 2} \right)^i + \frac{k}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n(n + 1)}\right)\right) \\
  ~ = ~ & 1 - \frac{k}{2}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) + \left(\left\{ n^2 \sum_{i = 2}^{\infty}{k \choose i}\left(\frac{-1}{2n + 2} \right)^i + \frac{k}{2}\left(\frac{n}{n + 1}\right)\right\} \middle/ n^2 \right)
 \end{align}$$

This has the form required for Gauss's test, with $A = k/2$ and $s = 2$. It remains to determine whether the absolute value of the bracketed expression is bounded by some positive number. We see that it is, since the absolute value of $kn/2(n + 1)$ is bounded by $|k|/2$. In addition, the absolute value of $n^2$ times the above series indexed at $2$ is bounded by some positive constant $\phi$. Thus, the absolute value of the function parameter to Gauss's test is bounded above by $\phi + |k|/2$ (work omitted). So the series converges if $k/2 > 1$, $i$.$e$., if $k > 2$, and diverges if $k/2 \leq 1$, $i$.$e$., if $k \leq 2$.

**Here is my question.** I am trying to work through this text using only those results previously introduced, and Apostol hasn't yet introduced the generalized binomial series. My conclusion is that this problem was supposed to be solved without using the binomial series, or facts about its convergence and divergence. So how would one go about solving this problem **without** expanding $(1 - 1/(2n + 2))^k$ using the binomial series, assuming that $k$ is an arbitrary real number? My only thought is that I should decompose $k$ into its integer and fractional parts, then use the binomial theorem for integral values. But then it's difficult to apply Gauss's test with negative values of $k$.

Comment: Shouldn't you just simply use the fact that the product in question is telescopic, as in the answer to [this question here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292594/is-the-expression-sum-n-1-infty-prod-k-1n-left1-frac23k-right), for instance ?

Comment: The problem specifically asks for a solution using Gauss's test, in the formulation given above, so using the telescoping property of infinite series wouldn't help in this case. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the generalized mean value theorem, for $0<x<1$ we have
$$
\ln(1-x) = - x - \frac1{(1-\xi)^2} \frac{x^2}2 \quad\text{and}\quad e^{-x} = 1 - x + e^{-\eta} \frac{x^2}2
$$
for some $0\le\xi,\eta\le x$. In particular, for $0<x\le\frac12$ we have
$$
-x-2x^2 \le \ln (1-x) \le -x \quad\text{and}\quad 1-x \le e^{-x} \le 1 - x + x^2.
$$
Therefore for $0<x\le\frac1{2k}$ (we can assume $k\ge2$ and use the comparison test for smaller $k$),
$$
(1-x)^k = \exp(k \ln (1-x)) \le \exp(-kx) \le 1 - kx + k^2x^2
$$
and
$$
(1-x)^k = \exp(k \ln (1-x)) \ge \exp(-kx-2kx^2) \ge 1-kx-2kx^2.
$$
We conclude that
$$
\bigg( 1 - \frac1{2n+1} \bigg)^k = 1 - \frac k{2n+1} + \frac{g(n)}{(2n+1)^2}
$$
where $|g(n)| \le k^2$. One can easily convert this into the exact form required by Gauss's test.

Comment: I'm having some trouble deriving the inequalities from the extended mean value theorem, but the rest of the proof is great. I never thought to express the relevant term using the exponential function, but now that you have, it makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to look at the problem.

Comment: No problem! $a^b = e^{b\ln a}$ is a surprisingly powerful trick. As for the inequalities, we're just looking for the largest/smallest values of $1/(1-\xi)^2$ and $e^{-\eta}$; in fact they give even stronger inequalities than those in the answer - I just weakened them to make them simpler to write down.